# SVG infinite animation lead to memory increase and high CPU utilization

Tags: css, google-chrome, memory, svg

I made a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5up9fpo/4/), it only has three same svg tags with css3 animation, when run it on chrome ( version: 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)) in windows, it turns out memory leaks when running for a while, here is the snapshot, the task manager shows memory increases!!!

[image: start test]
[image: end test]

I also test on the Mac, the result shows: not only memory increase, but also high cpu occupancy.

[image: test on mac]

the demo is so simple, I can't find some where wrong, does someone has meet such problem? Thanks?

the svg code is here:

```
<svg class="line-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="224" height="73.969" viewBox="0 0 224 73.969">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M635,413H779c9.5,0,18.685,1.462,26,10s51,59,51,59" transform="translate(-633.5 -411.5)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah, same deal in Firefox too. Must be computationally expensive to render it.

Comment: If you have found a memory leak in Chrome (and/or Firefox) I am sure they would be pleased to hear about it.  You should report it on their bug trackers.

Comment: issuse: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642601